I can't create a local branch with git bash
After I created a local branch with git bash by entering "git checkout -b new-main", the git bash can't show the local branch with the command "git branch --all". The problem is shown in the picture. How can I solve this problem?
problem
I try this command again in a new folder, but the problem still exists.

Use text to show code and errors instead of screenshots

Are you sure the output isn't in the colour of the terminal background? Can you select the "empty" line and try to copy/paste it?

Almost a dup, or probably close enough to this question

After a repository is initialized, there is an unborn branch (usually master). git checkout -b new-main renames the unborn branch as new-main. git branch does not print unborn branches. You need to create a commit on the branch. However, it's not mentioned in git branch.

Once you commit something to your branch, you will see
$ git branch
* new-main


The branch should show up without commits.

@BenjaminW. No. Immediately after git init commands git branch or even git branch --all show nothing.

You're right. Would have been great information to have that the repository is brand new ¯_(ツ)_/¯
